# Cant figure out what is happening - C

Tags: c

```
struct line {
    char* string;
    struct line* next;
};
```

Can someone please explain what is happening?
Ex:

- Creating a structure "line"
- This structure has a char variable "string" -> Whats with the "*" ??
- In this structure we create a new one called "line*" -> Whats with the "*" ??
- New struct has a field "next"

Comment: Read about pointers.

Comment: Take a few steps back. Structs should be in a far later chapter than pointers in any book about C.

Comment: The `struct` defines a node for a **linked list**. The `*` indicates that a struct field is a pointer. So `char* string;` is a pointer to the data the node is initialised with. And `struct line* next;` points to the next node (the same type) being a link to the next record in the list. The last record in the chain will have `NULL` in this field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct line {  // create structure
char* string;   // here * represent pointer and this line creates character pointer named string 
struct line* next;  // create pointer to structure named next
};
```

Refer this tutorial
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson6.html

Here `line` is structure.

Inside it you are creating pointer to `line` and pointer name is `next`

Comment: Thank you! But does " int fun(struct line *list){...} " -> mean that this function takes in a Pointer(called list) of a type line ??

Comment: here `fun` takes pointer to structure (called list) as an argument

Answer (score 4):

Basically, `string` and `line` in your structure are not data items, but *pointers* to the place in memory where the actual data items are located.

You can learn more in this [tutorial on pointers in C](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm).